# Extending a third pary ecore metamodel

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I would like to create my own metamodel by extending a third party EMF meta model. Currently I am using a third party ecore-model and would like to add an extra attribute to a specific EClass. I cannot change the existing metamodel due to the opensource license agreement. I have searched internet for the solutions, but failed to find any. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look to the EMF-Facet project:

https://www.eclipse.org/facet/

> ...EMF Facet proposes a solution to extend existing Ecore metamodels without having to modify them. The idea is to provide non-intrusive mechanisms to add new features (types, attributes, operations and references) to a metamodel...

I'm not sure that exactly what you are searching for, but perhaps it can give your ideas or pointers to others technologies.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. Before putting the question here, I actually saw the Emf Facet, but failed to find any supporting documents/help for getting started with this. If you dont mind, could you please guide me to the Emf facet help/tutorial.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used EMF-Facet. I for what the technology is used for, but that's all, sorry. You can try to look at their example project. I hope it could help you.